# Simulation of Lorenz System crashes

Tags: ode, gekko

I only just started exploring Gekko and tried simulating the Lorenz ODE system.
Unfortunately, I get an error ("no solution found") for a simple std case the runs fine using scipy.

The problem solves fine if I only integrate up to say time=0.5 instead of 1.0

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)

sigma = 10.; rho   = 28.0; beta  = 8./3.

x = m.Var(value=10); y = m.Var(value=10); z = m.Var(value=10)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(x.dt()== sigma*(y - x))
m.Equation(y.dt()== x*(rho -z) - y)
m.Equation(z.dt()== x*y - beta*z)
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.nodes = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(x.value, y.value)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential simulation `m.options.IMODE=7` solves successfully. The simultaneous simulation is a larger problem (1782 Variables/Equations vs. 18 Variables/Equations). It also solves successfully if you reduce `m.options.NODES=3` (1188 Variables) or increase the maximum iterations `m.options.MAX_ITER=300`. It failed previously because it needed 267 iterations to find the solution and the maximum iteration limit for IPOPT is 200 by default.

[image: Lorenz]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)

sigma = 10.; rho   = 28.0; beta  = 8./3.

x = m.Var(value=10); y = m.Var(value=10); z = m.Var(value=10)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(x.dt()== sigma*(y - x))
m.Equation(y.dt()== x*(rho -z) - y)
m.Equation(z.dt()== x*y - beta*z)
m.options.IMODE = 7
m.options.nodes = 4
m.solve(disp=True)

plt.plot(x.value, y.value)
plt.show()
```